# <div> overflow with "float:right"

Tags: html, css

I use the following line to generate a chat message from javascript:

```
var d = '<div class="triangle-border2 left">' + message + 
        '<span style="flex: 1 1 30px"></span><span style="float:right; font-size:80%; color:#5a8f00;margin-top:2px">' + 
         h + ':' + m + '</span></div>';
```

`message` is the message body, `h` is the hour and `m` is the minute. The `div` has a maximum width in its style. Here is the output for some messages:

[image]

What is the problem with the 'kkkk' and 'nnnnn' lines that makes the time  overflows outside the div? Why doesn't it behave like the 'mmmmmm' line? How can I fix it?

Note: The browser is Chromium, and this is fixed.

Comment: Can you provide a minimal, complete and verifiable example? https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: May I suggest putting your styling into a couple of neat classes that you can apply to each appended element, rather than inject a bunch of styling for each one. It would just be a lot tidier (and would fight my hatred of inline styles).

Comment: What's the empty span for `<span style="flex: 1 1 30px"></span>`?

Comment: @JuanFerreras Well, whenever a message arrives, the value of `d` is appended to a panel. It is not easy to provide a minimal, complete and verifiable example, as the system is rather complex. I tried to simplify to the maximum.

Comment: @DBS You are right. This is just a testing stage. Things will get much tidier later. Thanks

Comment: @Aziz I use it to fill the gap between the last character of the message and the time. Is it not necessary? I will try to remove it.

Comment: @AhmadWabbi, I think all Juan is asking for is the output html for the bubble and the css too - so we can see what is rendered and how to fix it.  To get this, you can use chrome to inspect element once it is rendered and then just copy the code

Comment: @Pete The problem is in css. This is a Sencha ExtJS 6 modern application , where the final style of the bubbles is the result of the mixtures of many classes generated by the framework. Anyway, I will do that and update the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try giving them `overflow-y: hidden;`

I don't know why but that sometimes resolves my similar issues by forcing the div to expand rather than allow content to overflow

Answer (score 2):

You are not clearing your float:

```
.triangle-border2:after {
    content:'';
    display:block;
    height:0;
    overflow:hidden;
    clear:right;
}
```